# Can we call a hidden service?

Tags: ros, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I saw that ROS2 use some hidden services.
These services can be displayed with the command

> ros2 service --include-hidden-services list -t

When I tried to call one of these services with his type, cli returns me this message : `The passed service type is invalid` with the type given by the previous command

So, I was wondering if it is possible to call one of theses services ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381629/can-we-call-a-hidden-service-?/) by [TeaTea](https://answers.ros.org/users/77027/teatea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Sorry for the late reply. So, I tried the same thing and it looks like you can't call the service cancel service directly. I am not quite sure of the reasoning behind this but to you can simply cancel the send goal by Ctrl +C the initial request. So exposing that service to be called doesn't really gain the user much.

However,

to get the same functionality in code you simply need to call the function below.

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/rolling/rclcpp_action/include/rclcpp_action/client.hpp#L530.

---

Originally posted by [josho.wallace@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/104275/josho.wallace@gmail.com/) with karma: 16 on 2022-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0